# How to get current user's information using session

Tags: mysql, asp.net, odbc

I have a problem in this line of code:

myCommands = New OdbcCommand("select * from customer where uname='" + Session("user") + "'", myConnections)

my goal here is to display all the user's information in a page tab, but it only shows a blank page.

Comment: myCommands = New OdbcCommand("select * from customer where lower(uname) = lower(@user)"), myConnections);
myCommands.Parameters.Add("@user", OdbcDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["user"].ToString(); Try out this

Comment: thank you for your help sir! :)

Comment: If it solved your problem, I will post that as answer, you will accept that and your question will be automatically "solved", so others also will be able to see the answer. If not, I will not post it

Comment: it had solved my problem sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

```
myCommands = New OdbcCommand("select * from customer where lower(uname) = lower(@user)"), myConnections); 
myCommands.Parameters.Add("@user", OdbcDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["user"].ToString();
```

This solved a problem.